# Process WCS data from EMODnet using R

Tags: raster, r, wcs

**edit: setting `mode = "wb"` to download the file is crucial for correct reading using solution by Spacedman**

I'm trying to get raster data on depth from [EMODnet](https://emodnet.ec.europa.eu/en) into R to analyse, using the WCS service.

Following the examples [here](https://portal.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/services/#wcs), I've constructed the following file called "request2.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="1.1.1" service="WCS"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1 http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1/wcsAll.xsd">
   <ows:Identifier>emodnet:mean</ows:Identifier>
   <wcs:DomainSubset>
      <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
         <ows:LowerCorner>43.48729 -2.5319802324929</ows:LowerCorner>
         <ows:UpperCorner>44.016457 -1.634064</ows:UpperCorner>
      </ows:BoundingBox>
   </wcs:DomainSubset>
   <wcs:Output store="true" format="image/tiff">
      <wcs:GridCRS>
         <wcs:GridBaseCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326</wcs:GridBaseCRS>
         <wcs:GridType>urn:ogc:def:method:WCS:1.1:2dSimpleGrid</wcs:GridType>
         <wcs:GridOffsets>0.0020881772848672093 -0.0020833346456692954</wcs:GridOffsets>
         <wcs:GridCS>urn:ogc:def:cs:OGC:0.0:Grid2dSquareCS</wcs:GridCS>
      </wcs:GridCRS>
   </wcs:Output>
</wcs:GetCoverage>
```

I try to process this using the following code in R:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(raster)
xml <- paste(readLines("Request2.xml"),collapse = "\n")

myheader=c(Connection="close", 
            'Content-Type' = "application/xml",
             'Content-length'=nchar(xml))

response <- getURL(url = "http://ows.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/wcs?",
                   postfields = xml,
                   httpheader = myheader)

xmlresp <- xmlTreeParse(response, asText = TRUE,useInternalNodes=TRUE)
link <- xmlGetAttr(getNodeSet(xmlresp,'//wcs:Coverages/wcs:Coverage/ows:Reference' )[[1]],
           "href")
download.file(link, destfile = "test.tiff",
              mode = "wb")

ras <- terra::rast("test.tiff")
```

Everything works, until I try to extract the raster information. I keep getting a message that the data is rotated, and I should use `rectify()`. But doing so loses all information. Furthermore, upon inspection it seems that the information isn't read correctly:

```
> ras <- terra::rast("test.tiff")
Warning: [rast] the data in this file are rotated. Use 'rectify' to fix that> 
> ras
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 431, 253, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0, 0  (x, y)
extent      : -1.634064, -1.634064, 43.48729, 43.48729  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : test.tiff 
name        : test
```

I've looked at drivers for gdal and feel a bit like I'm drowning. Anywone who can point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) `  is wrong.  epsg:4326 is lat/long

Comment: I think the `terra` package makes a real dog's breakfast from this file, getting the extent wrong and being unable to rectify it. I'd consider a bug report to terra (ignore raster package's problems, its less priority for the developer...)

Comment: @nmtoken woopsie... Don't know how to fix that though. I'm a novice when it comes to geostat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stars` seems to be better at handling rotated, sheared, and general curvilinear grids. In this case the TIFF seems to have a slight shear angle to it:

```
> rs = read_stars("test.tiff")
> rs
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
              Min. 1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.  Max.
test.tiff  -2221.4  -867.4 -416.7852 -534.6465 -127.5312 -42.5
dimension(s):
  from  to   offset delta refsys point values x/y
x    1 253 -1.63406     0 WGS 84 FALSE   NULL [x]
y    1 431  43.4873     0 WGS 84 FALSE   NULL [y]
sheared raster with parameters: -0.00208333232596961 0.00209156916996049
```

Plotting is slow because it has to compute all the shears for every pixel. Ugh.

You can warp to a rectilinear grid:

Define a new grid based on the bbox of the raster:

```
> ng = st_as_stars(st_bbox(rs))
> ng
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
        Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
values     0       0      0    0       0    0
dimension(s):
  from  to   offset       delta refsys point values x/y
x    1 332 -2.53198  0.00270786 WGS 84    NA   NULL [x]
y    1 196  44.0165 -0.00270786 WGS 84    NA   NULL [y]
```

You can probably adjust numbers of rows and columns. And then warp:

```
> rss = st_warp(rs, ng)
> rss
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
              Min. 1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.  Max. NA's
test.tiff  -2220.2  -867.4 -417.8477 -535.0106 -127.4912 -42.5  332
dimension(s):
  from  to   offset       delta refsys point values x/y
x    1 332 -2.53198  0.00270786 WGS 84    NA   NULL [x]
y    1 196  44.0165 -0.00270786 WGS 84    NA   NULL [y]
```

`plot(rss)` then gives you:

[image]

If you need this in raster/terra then conversions should be simple. Note this warping is a lossy process. I think the shearing here is possibly minor enough that you could ignore it in some way but not sure how to do that...

Comment: Thx for the effort! I got closer, but I still get a very large deviation from your output. The attributes I get range from -3.376278e+38  to 3.232712e+38 , quite a difference with the -2220 to -42.5 you get. Any idea what might be the difference in my setup?

Comment: Version of underlying GDAL library? What does library(stars) say about the things it links to?  What version of stars? I have: stars 0.5-3 and "Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE"

Comment: I have version 0.6.0, and "linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE". So that might explain the differenc in outcome. But even in the plot you show, there's some artifacts that shouldn't be there. Damn, geostats is hard!

Comment: I can hit myself. When downloading the file, setting `mode = "wb"` helps LOL. Sorry for wasting your time and thx for the tip about rast, really helps!